# Precedence of Spring boot profile specific and spring.config.import properties

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot version: 2.5.0

I've different property files. 3 inside the jar and one on the server (for overriding the properties with server specific)

1. application.properties
2. application-dev.properties
3. application-prod.properties

The active profile and external properties' path is configured in the application.properties.

```
spring.profiles.active=@prodProfile@
spring.config.import=optional:file:./application-local.properties
```

Where the values of @prodProfile@ is coming from the profile configuration part of pom.xml.

```
    <properties>
        <prodProfile>prod</prodProfile>
    </properties>
```

If I have same properties in application-prod.properties and application-local.properties, which has precedence? When I tested, I've found that profile specific has precedence. Not able to override the property value with spring.config.import. Is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behaviour. As [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.importing), files imported using `spring.config.import` are "treated as additional documents inserted immediately below the one that declares the import".

In your case, you are importing the file into `application.properties` so it will be treated as general, non-profile-specific configuration. As such, profile-specific properties will take precedence.